# JavaScript can't convert Hindi/Arabic numbers to real numeric variables

Tags: javascript, parsing, number-formatting

I'm trying to use a DOM coming from an external source, and in it there are some numeric values in Hindi/Arabic transcription, like `"۱۶۶۰"`, and when I want to convert it into numeric value I get `NaN`.

What's wrong here?

A small code snippet to be tried:

```js
alert(Number("۱۶۶۰") + ' - ' + Number("1660"));
```

Comment: I tried your code in Chrome's console, and I got `TypeError: Object function Number() { [native code] } has no method 'parseLocale'`. No luck searching Mozilla's documentation either. Is that an IE only thing?

Comment: No need to use `parseLocale` method.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't [yet](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=globalization:globalization) [support](http://es5.github.io/#x7.8.3) [parsing](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.2) such numbers.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Well, the [`Number` function](http://es5.github.io/#x15.7.1) does expect the digits 0 to 9 and does not handle arabic ones.

You will need to take care of that yourself:

```js
function parseArabic(str) {
  return Number(str
    .replace(/[٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩]/g, d => d.charCodeAt(0) - 1632) // convert Arabic digits
    .replace(/[۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹]/g, d => d.charCodeAt(0) - 1776) // convert Persian digits
  );
}
// usage example:
console.log( parseArabic("۱۶۶۰") )
```

Comment: The first number set is Arabic, the second one is [Persian](http://sartre2.byu.edu/persian/persianword/numbers.htm).

Comment: Because I couldn't find any answer for the other way around, here it is (Arabic only)


    function eurToArab(num) {
      return num.toString().replace(/\d/g, function(d) {
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(d[0], 10) + 1632);
      });
    }

Comment: Are there any examples of number systems that do not use Base 10 that we may need to handle?

Comment: @RichardCorfield [None that would matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numeral_systems), at least not in this question

Answer (score 15):

I would suggest you handle it at a lower level: replace the Arabic digits with the corresponding ASCII digits and then convert.

For example:

```
>a='\u0661\u0666\u0666\u0660'
"١٦٦٠"
>b='\u06f1\u06f6\u06f6\u06f0'
"۱۶۶۰"
>r=/[\u0660-\u0669\u06F0-\u06F9]/g;
/[\u0660-\u0669\u06F0-\u06F9]/g
>a.replace(r,function(c) { return '0123456789'[c.charCodeAt(0)&0xf]; } )
"1660"
>b.replace(r,function(c) { return '0123456789'[c.charCodeAt(0)&0xf]; } )
"1660"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function called *paserNumber* that converts a string representing a number into an actual JS [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) object. It can also accept number strings with fractions (decimal numbers) and Arabic/Persian/English thousands separators. I don't know whether this solution is the best, performance-wise.

```js
function parseNumber(numberText: string) {
    return Number(
        // Convert Persian (and Arabic) digits to Latin digits
        normalizeDigits(numberText)
        // Convert Persian/Arabic decimal separator to English decimal separator (dot)
        .replace(/٫/g, ".")
        // Remove other characters such as thousands separators
        .replace(/[^\d.]/g, "")
    );
}

const persianDigitsRegex = [/۰/g, /۱/g, /۲/g, /۳/g, /۴/g, /۵/g, /۶/g, /۷/g, /۸/g, /۹/g];
const arabicDigitsRegex = [/٠/g, /١/g, /٢/g, /٣/g, /٤/g, /٥/g, /٦/g, /٧/g, /٨/g, /٩/g];

function normalizeDigits(text: string) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        text = text
                .replace(persianDigitsRegex[i], i.toString())
                .replace(arabicDigitsRegex[i], i.toString());
    }
    return text;
}
```

Note that the *parse* function is quite forgiving and the number string can be a combination of Persian/Arabic/Latin numerals and separators.

#### Side note

After getting a *Number* you can format it back however you want with [Number.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) function:

```js
let numberString = "۱۲۳۴.5678";
let number = parseNumber(numberString);
val formatted1 = number.toLocaleString("fa"); // OR "fa-IR" for IRAN
val formatted2 = number.toLocaleString("en"); // OR "en-US" for USA
val formatted3 = number.toLocaleString("ar-EG"); // OR "ar" which uses western numerals
```

For more information about formatting numbers, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70467617/8583692).

Answer (score 0):

This is a function which can convert **all** Unicode decimal digits to ASCII decimal digits. Unicode has a `Nd` (Number decimal) for the digits and we can search for it using `/\p{Nd}/u` regex. The category has 650 characters - that is 65 different numeric alphabets, which makes it impractical to hardcode the `replace` calls, if you'd want to support them all.

We can take advantage of the fact that all numeric blocks either start at U+...0, or end at U+...F, as you can verify in this table: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Nd
Then we can simply take the last hexadecimal digit of the codepoint (using `& 0xf`), and subtract 6 for the blocks that end at U+...F.
This is easily checked by asking whether `code | 0xf` is also in `Nd`, using the same regex we are searching with.
Fortunately, no Nd character is above U+FFFF, we don't have to work with UTF-16 surrogate pairs.

```js
function normalizeDigits(str) {
  // find all characters which are DecimalNumber (property Nd), except for ASCII 0-9
  return str.replace(/(?![0-9])\p{Nd}/ug, g => {
    // all Nd blocks start at 0x...0 or end at 0x...F (and starts at 0x...6)
    // if it starts at 0x...0, the ASCII decimal number is (i & 0xf)
    // if it ends at 0x...F, the ASCII decimal number is (i & 0xf) - 6
    // we recognize the 2 cases by testing if code | 0xf == 0x...F is still a decimal number
    const code = g.charCodeAt(0)
    return (code & 0xf) - 6 * /\p{Nd}/u.test(String.fromCodePoint(code | 0xf))
  })
}
```