# How can we have a Persian (Shamsi) calendar in angular 2

Tags: angular

Is there any way to make a persion (Hejri Shamsi) Calender in angular 2 or is there any way to convert Gergorian calender to persion?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514454/convert-gregorian-date-to-persianjalali-date-in-angular-2-and-ionic-2

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert the date in `.ts` use `jalali-moment`

```
import * as moment from 'jalali-moment';
let jalaliDate = moment("1989/1/24").format('jYYYY/jM/jD'); // 1367/11/4
```

but if you need sth to use in `.html` use `jalali-angular-datepicker`

more info [here](https://github.com/fingerpich/jalali-angular-datepicker)