# How to convert Persian and Arabic digits of a string to English using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arabic, farsi

How can I convert Persian/Arabic numbers to English numbers with a simple function?

```
arabicNumbers = ["١", "٢", "٣", "٤", "٥", "٦", "٧", "٨", "٩", "٠"]
persianNumbers = ["۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹", "۰"]
```

It is the same schema, but the code pages are different.

Comment: Wait! .. Arabic numbers are 01234..9 ... those are Hindu-Arabic numbers! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals

Comment: no its really arabic, trust me ;)

Comment: You may use them in middle east, but those 012..9 are the Arabic numerals, not English numerals.

Comment: we usually have many text with these characters and want to convert it.
you dont really know the arabic language and just check the english standards for arabic. all arabian people use these numbers (۱, ۲, ۳) in handwriting not english numbers!

Comment: in iraq and some other country use ۱, ۲, ۳, please stop this convertation, i have these letters in my arabic text and want to convert, thank you

Comment: its answered thank you

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35288093/8583692).

Answer (score 95, accepted):

#### Use this simple function to convert your string

```
var
persianNumbers = [/۰/g, /۱/g, /۲/g, /۳/g, /۴/g, /۵/g, /۶/g, /۷/g, /۸/g, /۹/g],
arabicNumbers  = [/٠/g, /١/g, /٢/g, /٣/g, /٤/g, /٥/g, /٦/g, /٧/g, /٨/g, /٩/g],
fixNumbers = function (str)
{
  if(typeof str === 'string')
  {
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
      str = str.replace(persianNumbers[i], i).replace(arabicNumbers[i], i);
    }
  }
  return str;
};
```

Be careful, in this code the persian numbers codepage are different with  the arabian numbers.

#### Example

```
var mystr = 'Sample text ۱۱۱۵۱ and ٢٨٢٢';
mystr = fixNumbers(mystr);
```

[Refrence](https://gist.github.com/AliMD/e5033db9e3943e78930f)

Answer (score 139):

**Oneliner** of all 6 possible translations between English, Arabic, and persian Digits.

**Caution!!** Please note that this solution is not efficient and therefore is not recommended for production code. It is only good as a oneliner. In these methods the '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹' string is created every time for every digit! It is much wiser to create the string once and store it in a variable and use that variable instead. Also, most likely a simple `for-loop` is much faster!

```
const e2p = s => s.replace(/\d/g, d => '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'[d])
const e2a = s => s.replace(/\d/g, d => '٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩'[d])

const p2e = s => s.replace(/[۰-۹]/g, d => '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'.indexOf(d))
const a2e = s => s.replace(/[٠-٩]/g, d => '٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩'.indexOf(d))

const p2a = s => s.replace(/[۰-۹]/g, d => '٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩'['۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'.indexOf(d)])
const a2p = s => s.replace(/[٠-٩]/g, d => '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'['٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩'.indexOf(d)])

e2p("asdf1234") // asdf۱۲۳۴
e2a("asdf1234") // asdf١٢٣٤
p2e("asdf۱۲۳۴") // asdf1234
a2e("asdf١٢٣٤") // asdf1234
p2a("asdf۱۲۳۴") // asdf١٢٣٤
a2p("asdf١٢٣٤") // asdf۱۲۳۴
```

**Explaination:**

- `(s => f(s))(x)` is a lambda function that is immediately executed, and will be equal to f(x)
- `s.replace(pattern, function)` looks for matches of pattern in s, for every match m it will replace m with `function(m)` in the string.
- `/\d/g` is a regex pattern, `\d` means a digit in the English language, `g` means global. If you don't specify the `g` it will only match the first occurrence, otherwise it will match all the occurrences.
- In this case for every English digit `d` in the string, that digit will be replaced by `'۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'[d]` so, 3 will be replaced by the third index in that list(`'۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'`) which is '۳'
- `/[۰-۹]/g` is the equivalent regex for Persian digits this time we can't use the same method, before we took advantage of the fact that javascript is dynamically typed and that d is automatically converted from  a string(regex match) to a number(array index) (you can do `'1234'['1']` in javascript which is the same as `'1234'[1]`)
- but this time we can't do that because `'1234'['۱']` is invalid. so we use a trick here and use `indexOf` which is a function that tells us the index of an element in an array(here a character in a string) so, `'۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'.indexOf(۳)` will give us `3` because `'۳'` is the third index in the string `'۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'`

Comment: The question says, Persian numbers to English!

Comment: This is the best answer !
Could you provide some explanation on how it works though.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation :)

Comment: I'm in love with that solution!

Comment: @yukashima-huksay I have Q: why you write /[۰-۹]/g for persian & /[٠-٩]/g for arabic? is there any reason for that?

Comment: @mohammadjawadBarati they are typed in the same order (0 first, 9 after) but the rendering in stackoverflow is problematic.

Comment: this solution must be accepted! very simple and useful.

Comment: In these methods '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹' string created every time for every number! Why you dont use seperate var? and I think simple for is much much faster!

Comment: @S.AliMihandoost you are very right Ali! Thank you! This solution was mostly aimed at c00l kids who are looking for oneliners. And those who just want some quick script for a one time task. I added your important notice to the post.

Answer (score 25):

this is a simple way to do that:

```
function toEnglishDigits(str) {

    // convert persian digits [۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹]
    var e = '۰'.charCodeAt(0);
    str = str.replace(/[۰-۹]/g, function(t) {
        return t.charCodeAt(0) - e;
    });

    // convert arabic indic digits [٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩]
    e = '٠'.charCodeAt(0);
    str = str.replace(/[٠-٩]/g, function(t) {
        return t.charCodeAt(0) - e;
    });
    return str;
}
```

an example:

```
console.log(toEnglishDigits("abc[0123456789][٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩][۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹]"));
// expected result => abc[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]
```

Comment: nice approach my friend

Answer (score 20):

The most **High Performance** (Fast & Accurate) function that can support both **Persian/Arabic** digits (Unicode numeral characters) is this:

```js
function toEnDigit(s) {
    return s.replace(/[\u0660-\u0669\u06f0-\u06f9]/g,    // Detect all Persian/Arabic Digit in range of their Unicode with a global RegEx character set
        function(a) { return a.charCodeAt(0) & 0xf }     // Remove the Unicode base(2) range that not match
    )
}

sample='English: 0123456789 - Persian: ۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹ - Arabic: ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩';
     // English: 0123456789 - Persian: 0123456789 - Arabic: 0123456789

console.log( toEnDigit(sample) );
```

##### How it work

First by using [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) + [RegEx Character Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes) in range of [Arabic Digit Unicode](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/arabic/#:%7E:text=Arabic-Indic%20digits) `U+0660 - U+0669 = ٠ ... ۹` & [Persian Digit Unicode](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/arabic/#:%7E:text=Eastern%20Arabic-Indic%20digits) `U+06F0 - U+06F9 = ۰ ... ۹` it will detect any character of the string that match it.

Then because [Basic Latin Digits (ASCII)](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/basic-latin/#:%7E:text=ASCII%20digits) have same ends in Unicode `U+003`**`0`** `- U+003`**`9`**`=`**`0`**`-`**`9`**, So if we remove the difference of them in base, the end can be same.
For that we can use [Bitwise AND (&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND) operation between their Char-code by using [charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) to just the same part stay.

Explain:

```js
// x86 (Base 10) --> Binary (Base 2)

'٤'.charCodeAt(0);   // 1636 (Base 10)
'۴'.charCodeAt(0);   // 1780 (Base 10)

(1636).toString(2);  // 0000000000000000000001100110 0100 (Base 2)
(1780).toString(2);  // 0000000000000000000001101111 0100 (Base 2)
(4).toString(2);     // 0000000000000000000000000000 0100 (Base 2)

// We need a         // 0000000000000000000000000000 1111 (Base 2)
// To And it, for keeping just the 1's
// 0xf = 15
(15).toString(2);    // 0000000000000000000000000000 1111 (Base 2)

// So
(
1780                 // 0000000000000000000001101111 0100 (Base 2)
&                    // AND (Operation)
15                   // 0000000000000000000000000000 1111 (Base 2)
)
==
4                    // 0000000000000000000000000000 0100 (Base 2)  
// ---> true       

// Also              (1636 & 15) == 4    <--- true
```

###### Minified version (All Browsers):

```js
function toEnDigit(s){return s.replace(/[\u0660-\u0669\u06f0-\u06f9]/g,function(a){return a.charCodeAt(0)&15})}
```

###### OneLiner (Modern Browsers)

```
const toEnDigit=s=>s.replace(/[٠-٩۰-۹]/g,a=>a.charCodeAt(0)&15);
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice and practical solution. That literally saved my day.

Comment: Your method is excellent and I have created a shorter method based on it (see above). Thanks

Answer (score 14):

best way to do that return index of number in array:

```
String.prototype.toEnglishDigits = function () {
    return this.replace(/[۰-۹]/g, function (chr) {
        var persian = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];
        return persian.indexOf(chr);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 10):

If the string may contain **both** "Arabic" and "Persian" numbers then a one-line "replace" can do the job as follows.

The Arabic and Persian numbers are converted to English equivalents. Other text remains unchanged.

```js
Num= "۳٣۶٦۵any٥۵٤۶32٠۰";     // Output should be "33665any55453200"

Num = Num.replace(/[٠-٩]/g, d => "٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩".indexOf(d)).replace(/[۰-۹]/g, d => "۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹".indexOf(d));

console.log(Num);
```

Comment: That's mixing of method of [yukashima](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58157015/7514010) answer and it is smart. But for being more compact & faster i suggest it be like this: ``Num.replace(/[٠-٩۰-۹]/g, d => d="٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹".indexOf(d) % 10);`` You can check methods performance here: https://jsben.ch/IaDxH

Comment: Nice one. Thanks.

Comment: I wish I could similarly make this here more performant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71421825/how-to-convert-persian-jalali-dates-to-other-18-calendar-dates-in-javascript-w

Answer (score 9):

Short and easy!

```
"۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹".replace(/([۰-۹])/g, function(token) { return String.fromCharCode(token.charCodeAt(0) - 1728); });
```

Or in a more modern manner

```
"۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹".replace(/([۰-۹])/g, token => String.fromCharCode(token.charCodeAt(0) - 1728));
```

Comment: this solution is the best as it has no typing issues and works best with typescript. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like this that uses the index of the number within the string to do the conversion:

```js
// Returns -1 if `fromNum` is not a numeric character
function convertNumber(fromNum) {
    var persianNums = '۰١۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹';
    return persianNums.indexOf(fromNum);
}

var testNum = '۴';
alert("number is: " + convertNumber(testNum));
```

Or map using a object like this:

```js
// Returns -1 if `fromNum` is not a numeric character
function convertNumber(fromNum) {
    var result;
    var arabicMap = {
        '٩': 9,
        '٨': 8,
        '٧': 7,
        '٦': 6,
        '٥': 5,
        '٤': 4,
        '٣': 3,
        '٢': 2,
        '١': 1,
        '٠': 0
    };
    result = arabicMap[fromNum];
    if (result === undefined) {
        result = -1;
    }
    return result;
}

var testNum = '٤';
alert("number is: " + convertNumber(testNum));
```

Comment: i want to convert inside a string

Comment: please clarify your question as it is currently very vague and doesn't specify exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 6):

Transforms any *Persian* or *Arabic* (or mixed) number to "*English*" numbers ([Hindu–Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals))

```js
var transformNumbers = (function(){
    var numerals = {
        persian : ["۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹"],
        arabic  : ["٠", "١", "٢", "٣", "٤", "٥", "٦", "٧", "٨", "٩"]
    };

    function fromEnglish(str, lang){
        var i, len = str.length, result = "";

        for( i = 0; i < len; i++ )
            result += numerals[lang][str[i]]; 

        return result;
    }

    return {
        toNormal : function(str){
            var num, i, len = str.length, result = "";

            for( i = 0; i < len; i++ ){
                num = numerals["persian"].indexOf(str[i]);
                num = num != -1 ? num : numerals["arabic"].indexOf(str[i]);
                if( num == -1 ) num = str[i];
                result += num; 
            }
              
            return result;
        },

        toPersian : function(str, lang){
            return fromEnglish(str, "persian");
        },

        toArabic : function(str){
            return fromEnglish(str, "arabic");
        }
    }
})();

//////// ON INPUT EVENT //////////////

document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].addEventListener('input', onInput_Normal);
document.querySelectorAll('input')[1].addEventListener('input', onInput_Arabic);

function onInput_Arabic(){
   var _n = transformNumbers.toArabic(this.value);
   console.clear();
   console.log( _n )
}

function onInput_Normal(){
   var _n = transformNumbers.toNormal(this.value);
   console.clear();
   console.log( _n )
}
```

```css
input{ width:90%; margin-bottom:1em; font-size:1.5em; padding:5px; }
```

```html
<input placeholder="write in Arabic numerals">

<input placeholder="write in normal numerals">
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function toEnglishDigits(str) {
  const persianNumbers = ["۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹", "۰"]
  const arabicNumbers = ["١", "٢", "٣", "٤", "٥", "٦", "٧", "٨", "٩", "٠"]
  const englishNumbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
  
  return str.split("").map(c => englishNumbers[persianNumbers.indexOf(c)] ||
      englishNumbers[arabicNumbers.indexOf(c)] || c).join("")
}

toEnglishDigits("۶٦۵any٥32") // "665any532"
```

Comment: very intelligent way to do that!

Answer (score 3):

Based on [MMMahdy-PAPION](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7514010/mmmahdy-papion) method, a short one-line to convert **both** Persian and Arabic numbers to English numbers and keep all other characters unchanged is the following:

```
const toEnDigit=n=>n.replace(/[٠-٩۰-۹]/g,n=>15&n.charCodeAt(0));
```

```js
const toEnDigit=n=>n.replace(/[٠-٩۰-۹]/g,n=>15&n.charCodeAt(0));


sample='English: 0123456789 - Persian (فارسی): ۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹ - Arabic (عربي): ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩';
// English: 0123456789 - Persian: 0123456789 - Arabic: 0123456789

console.log(toEnDigit(sample) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new [Persian-tools](https://github.com/persian-tools/persian-tools) library which is an awesome javascript library to deal with Persian words and numbers. Here is a sample for the task you asked for it:

```
import { digitsArToFa, digitsArToEn, digitsEnToFa, digitsFaToEn } from "persian-tools2";

digitsArToFa("٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"); // "۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹"
digitsArToEn("٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"); // "0123456789"
digitsEnToFa("123۴۵۶"); // "۱۲۳۴۵۶"
digitsFaToEn("۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹"); // "0123456789"
```

You can also find many other useful functionalities on the repository page of the library.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const convertToPersianDigits = (number) => number.toLocaleString('fa-IR')

convertToPersianDigits(100000)    //۱۰۰٬۰۰۰
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have your number string (a string representing a number) at hand, here is a function called *paserNumber* that converts that into an actual JS [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) object:

```js
function parseNumber(numberText: string) {
    return Number(
        // Convert Persian (and Arabic) digits to Latin digits
        normalizeDigits(numberText)
        // Convert Persian/Arabic decimal separator to English decimal separator (dot)
        .replace(/٫/g, ".")
        // Remove other characters such as thousands separators
        .replace(/[^\d.]/g, "")
    );
}

const persianDigitsRegex = [/۰/g, /۱/g, /۲/g, /۳/g, /۴/g, /۵/g, /۶/g, /۷/g, /۸/g, /۹/g];
const arabicDigitsRegex = [/٠/g, /١/g, /٢/g, /٣/g, /٤/g, /٥/g, /٦/g, /٧/g, /٨/g, /٩/g];

function normalizeDigits(text: string) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        text = text
                .replace(persianDigitsRegex[i], i.toString())
                .replace(arabicDigitsRegex[i], i.toString());
    }
    return text;
}
```

Note that the *parse* function is quite forgiving and the number string can be a combination of Persian/Arabic/Latin numerals and separators.

After getting a *Number* you can format it however you want with [Number.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) function:

```js
let numberString = "۱۲۳۴.5678";
let number = parseNumber(numberString);
let formatted1 = number.toLocaleString("fa"); // OR "fa-IR" for IRAN
let formatted2 = number.toLocaleString("en"); // OR "en-US" for USA
let formatted3 = number.toLocaleString("ar-EG"); // OR "ar" which uses western numerals
```

For more information about formatting numbers, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70467617/8583692).

Answer (score 1):

```
function persianToEnglishNumbers(persianNumber) {
const persianDigits = '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹';
const englishDigits = '0123456789';

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    persianNumber = persianNumber.replace(new RegExp(persianDigits[i], 'g'), englishDigits[i]);
}

return persianNumber;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For React solution using typescript this might be useful:

```
// https://gist.github.com/alieslamifard/364862613408a98139da3cab40abbeb9

import React, { InputHTMLAttributes, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

// Persian/Arabic To English Digit
const f2e = (event) => {
  event.target.value = event.target.value
    .replace(/[٠-٩]/g, (d) => '٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩'.indexOf(d))
    .replace(/[۰-۹]/g, (d) => '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'.indexOf(d));

  return event;
};

const useForwardedRef = (ref) => {
  const innerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ref) return;
    if (typeof ref === 'function') {
      ref(innerRef.current);
    } else {
      ref.current = innerRef.current;
    }
  }, [ref]);

  return innerRef;
};

const Input = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>>(
  (props, ref) => {
    const innerRef = useForwardedRef(ref);

    useEffect(() => {
      innerRef.current?.addEventListener('keyup', f2e);

      return () => {
        innerRef.current?.removeEventListener('keyup', f2e);
      };
    }, [innerRef]);

    return <input {...props} ref={innerRef} />;
  },
);

export default Input;
```

Simply use `Input` instead of native `input` in your form :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toLocaleString()`.

```
'1234567890'.toLocaleString('fa-IR')
// ۱۲۳٬۴۵۶٬۷۸۹٬۰
```

For removing separator from numbers, add this option:

```js
'1234567890'.toLocaleString('fa-IR', { useGrouping: false })
// ۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰
```