# How to convert string to ByteString in Ajax Post Request?

Tags: ajax, post, header, xmlhttprequest

I'd like to use ajax to retrieve a token.

In accordance to this [documentation](https://medium.com/@nolanbrown/august-lock-rest-apis-the-basics-7ec7f31e7874), below is the URL, request headers, and request body

```
POST https://api-production.august.com/session

Request Headers:

x-august-api-key: 727dba56-fe45–498d-b4aa-293f96aae0e5
x-kease-api-key: 727dba56-fe45–498d-b4aa-293f96aae0e5
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Version: 0.0.1
User-Agent: August/Luna-3.2.2

Request Body: (JSON Encoded)
{
  "installId": <Random UUID>,
  "password": "XXXXXXXX",
  "identifier": "phone:+15555551234"
}
```

I've tried to implement this with ajax as such

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://api-production.august.com/session",
            dataType: "json",
            headers:{
                "x-august-api-key":"727dba56-fe45–498d-b4aa-293f96aae0e5",
                "x-kease-api-key":"727dba56-fe45–498d-b4aa-293f96aae0e5",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept-Version": "0.0.1",
                "User-Agent": "August/Luna-3.2.2"
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({installId: "7fb17963-21a8-4c23-8f81-121ed3298ad8",
            password: "password",
            identifier: "phone:+18885554444"})})
```

However I dont get the token and I get the following response:

```
abort: function abort()
always: function always()
catch: function catch()
done: function add()
fail: function add()
getAllResponseHeaders: function getAllResponseHeaders()
getResponseHeader: function getResponseHeader()
overrideMimeType: function overrideMimeType()
pipe: function pipe()
progress: function add()
promise: function promise()
readyState: 0
responseJSON: undefined
setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader()
state: function state()
status: 0
statusCode: function statusCode()
statusText: "error"
then: function then()
```

The error is the following:

```
my error: ajax TypeError: Cannot convert string to ByteString because the character at index 13 has value 8211 which is greater than 255.
```

I've also tried running this in google chrome, but I get the following error:

```
"TypeError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Value is not a valid ByteString."
```

I've also tried the following to no avail as I get the same error:

```
   $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://api-production.august.com/session",
                dataType: "json",
                  beforeSend: function(request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("x-august-api-key", "727dba56-fe45–498d-b4aa-293f96aae0e5");
                  },
                data: JSON.stringify({installId: "7fb17963-21a8-4c23-8f81-121ed3298ad8",
                password: "password",
                identifier: "phone:+18885554444"})})
```

Comment: In my case the content of this answer is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31439605.

Answer (score 4):

Your first error is kinda vague but it does mention "the character at index 13" (aka the 14th character). Your second error helps you see that the problem comes from `setRequestHeader`. So you should look at the strings that you pass to `setRequestHeader` and more specifically, the 14th character in those strings.

1. x-august-api-`k`ey
2. 727dba56-fe45`–`498d-b4aa-293f96aae0e5

Now we ask ourselves, which one of these characters `k` or `–` is more likely to be causing us issues? It should be intuitive that the `–` is more likely to be the offending character so we take a closer look at it.

At this point we should be suspecting that we aren't using a hyphen character (ascii value of 45) but some other character that looks like a hyphen. Indeed, if we look up the ascii value 8211 (8211 comes from your first error) we see that the associated character is the en dash.

Some editors/viewers make the characters look different while others make it look the same. For me using Google Chrome to view this question, I can compare the hyphens in your key and I can see that the 2nd "hyphen" does not look like the rest. It's a tad longer.

```
hyphen:  -
en dash: –
```

So you should replace the en dash character with the hyphen character in your key. Then your string should be able to be converted to ByteString no problem.

Comment: The dash wasn't the issue with me, but the error pointing to a character at position _n_ was, so I looked and I had a char that looked like three periods `...` in my copy paste of the key, but was a single character. I removed that from the Bearer key I use, and the error is gone (from Swagger in this instance). +1

Comment: Further to my previous comment, it looks like this is an encoding bug in Firefox, I switched to new Edge(V.94) and did not have the same problem with the elipses character. 
Although removing the "wrong" char got rid of the ByteString error, I could not authenticate, now having a wrong token.