# Wicket.Ajax.Call.failure: Error while parsing response Value is not a valid ByteString

Tags: java, ajax, request, wicket

I'm getting the following error when I try to click on an RadioChoice button.

```
ERROR: Wicket.Ajax.Call.failure: Error while parsing response: TypeError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Value is not a valid ByteString.
```

I can't provide a code. Any idea about this error.

Comment: In my case the content of this answer is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31439605.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be something in the values of `header` variable passed to jQuery [here](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/147f6d33f839edd9a6eb53ce9c20b4cde07fc938/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/ajax/res/js/wicket-ajax-jquery.js#L711).
I guess it is the value of [lastFocusId](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/147f6d33f839edd9a6eb53ce9c20b4cde07fc938/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/ajax/res/js/wicket-ajax-jquery.js#L616) .
I'd recommend you to put a break point and see what values are being set and which one is not valid. Most probably `lastFocusId` has some Unicode characters which cannot be converted to ByteString.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I use Unicode characters in wicket:id.