# Use Non Arabic Numbers with intlDateTimeFormat

Tags: javascript

Cant seem to find the answer to this so asking it here. I want to use non arabic numbers for the arabic locale is this possible?

```
const intlDateTimeFormat.format(new Date());
intlDateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar-SA', { month: 'short', day: 'numeric' });
// "٢٠ شوال"
```

But i want...

```
const intlDateTimeFormat.format(new Date());
intlDateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar-SA', { something? , month: 'short', day: 'numeric' });
// "01 شوال"
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Maybe this can help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439604/how-to-convert-persian-and-arabic-digits-of-a-string-to-english-using-javascript) **How can I convert Arabic numbers to English numbers**

Comment: @Tim hope my answer below help fix the issue

Comment: @Tim you can also vote-up the correct answer :-) Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is to format a Date with an Arabic Locale (i.e. Arabic text) **but** with Latin (English) Numbers (or any other numbering system of your choice).

Please note that when using the Arabic Language locales the numbering system will default to the **Arabic-Eastern numbers** for ALL Arabic Locales (i.e. the numbers `"٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"` **EXCEPT** for five (5) Arabic locales that will use the Arabic-Western (Latin) Numbers `0123456789`; these are `ar-DZ`, `ar-EH`, `ar-LY`, `ar-MA`, and `ar-TN` locales.

As you are using `ar-SA` for Saudi Arabia the date will default to using the Arabic-Eastern Numbers `"٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"`.

You can change to using the Arabic-Western (Latin) Numbers `0123456789` irrespective of the locale used by either:

**1.** Specify `latn` as Unicode numbering system in the **locale**.

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar-SA-u-nu-latn',{month:'short',day:'numeric' }).format(new Date());
```

OR

**2.** Specify `latn` as a numbering system **options**.

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar-SA',{month:'short',day:'numeric',numberingSystem:'latn'}).format(new Date());
```

In either case, you will output an Arabic String but with English (Arabic-Western Numbers).

```
**There are other numbering systems that you can use**: 
 "arab", "arabext", " bali", "beng", "deva", "fullwide",
 " gujr", "guru", "hanidec", "khmr", " knda", "laoo",
 "latn", "limb", "mlym", " mong", "mymr", "orya",
 "tamldec", " telu", "thai", "tibt".
```

Here is an example.

```js
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar-SA-u-nu-latn',{month:'short',day:'numeric'}).format(new Date()));


console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar-SA',{month:'short',day:'numeric',numberingSystem:'latn'}).format(new Date()));


console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar-SA',{dateStyle: 'full',numberingSystem:'latn'}).format(new Date()));
```