# Is there a way to make JS Intl object to support classical Latin language?

Tags: javascript, latin

[Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) object is great for all sorts for formatting. It supports basically all modern languages. But I can't make it work with classical Latin.

Can it be supported all? Passing `'la'` as a locale doesn't seems to work.

I've tried this

```js
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('la', {
    dateStyle: 'full',
    timeStyle: 'short'
}).format(new Date())
```

But it returned this: `'Wednesday, 8 November 2023 at 19:05'`

The result is basically English.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67795992/use-non-arabic-numbers-with-intldatetimeformat

Comment: looks like it is not supported: `const locales = ['la']; const options = { localeMatcher: 'lookup' }; console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat.supportedLocalesOf(locales, options));`