# How to replace Arabic number strings to English?

Tags: javascript

I replace English number strings to Persian with a function like this :

```
const e2p = (s) => s.replace(/\d/g, (d) => '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'[d]);

e2p("211") // --> output is ۲۱۱
```

Now I want to do the opposite by changing arabic string numbers to english .

I tried this method but it didn't work :

```
const p2e = s => s.replace(/\d/g, d => '0123456789'[d]);

console.log(p2e('۲۱۱')); // outputs --> ۲۱۱
```

How can I do this in javascript ?

Comment: Use replace and put the Arabic numbers in the regex?

Comment: You could try subtracting `1728` by the ascii value to get the number then convert to Int.
Its the first thing that came to my mind

Comment: `/[\u06F0-\u06F9]/g`

Comment: The solution was discussed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31439605/1574766

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with this method :

```
const p2e = s => s.replace(/[۰-۹]/g, d => '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'.indexOf(d))

console.log(p2e('۲۱۱')); // outputs --> 211
```