# Convert English Numbers to Persian

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using the following JavaScript to convert all the English numbers showing on my website to Persian.

I realize that there are several ways to go about this and I have looked online and tried a few, however, this script does what I want it to do and it was really easy to implement except I want the phone number and date in my footer to be excluded from the conversion and remain English.

Not sure how I go about this in my PHP/HTML page.

On the second note, when my site is loading for a couple of seconds the numbers appear in English and quickly convert to Persian. Just wondering if there was a way that I could reduce this delay?

Here is my code:

```js
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var replaceDigits = function() {
var map =
[
"&\#1776;","&\#1777;","&\#1778;","&\#1779;","&\#1780;",
"&\#1781;","&\#1782;","&\#1783;","&\#1784;","&\#1785;"
]
document.body.innerHTML =
document.body.innerHTML.replace(
/\d(?=[^<>]*(<|$))/g,
function($0) { return map[$0] }
);
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = replaceDigits
</script>
```

Comment: I used `window.onload = replaceDigits` in my code an it resulted in horrible undefined behavior. I strongly recommend against using such methods...

Answer (score 41):

Here you are :)

```
function toFarsiNumber(n) {
    const farsiDigits = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];

    return n
      .toString()
      .split('')
      .map(x => farsiDigits[x])
      .join('');
  }
```

Another version!

```
function toFarsiNumber(n) {
    const farsiDigits = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];

    return n
        .toString()
        .replace(/\d/g, x => farsiDigits[x]);
}
```

Comment: The second version is just beautiful

Comment: The second is better, the first version keep numbers only and destroy any other characters

Comment: it has the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')`

Answer (score 18):

Here is the PHP function :

```
function toPersianNum($number)
    {
        $number = str_replace("1","۱",$number);
        $number = str_replace("2","۲",$number);
        $number = str_replace("3","۳",$number);
        $number = str_replace("4","۴",$number);
        $number = str_replace("5","۵",$number);
        $number = str_replace("6","۶",$number);
        $number = str_replace("7","۷",$number);
        $number = str_replace("8","۸",$number);
        $number = str_replace("9","۹",$number);
        $number = str_replace("0","۰",$number);
        return $number;
    }
```

Using :

```
$fa_num = toPersianNum(1234); // It returns ۱۲۳۴
$fa_date = toPersianNum('2016/05/10'); // It returns ۲۰۱۶/۰۵/۱۰
```

**JavaScript**

And here is the JavaScript function :

```
function toPersianNum( num, dontTrim ) {

    var i = 0,

        dontTrim = dontTrim || false,

        num = dontTrim ? num.toString() : num.toString().trim(),
        len = num.length,

        res = '',
        pos,

        persianNumbers = typeof persianNumber == 'undefined' ?
            ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'] :
            persianNumbers;

    for (; i < len; i++)
        if (( pos = persianNumbers[num.charAt(i)] ))
            res += pos;
        else
            res += num.charAt(i);

    return res;
}
```

Using :

```
var fa_num = toPersianNum(1234) // It returns ۱۲۳۴
var fa_date = toPersianNum('2016/05/10'); // It returns ۲۰۱۶/۰۵/۱۰
```

Be Happy :)

**UPDATE**

Here are `toEnglishNum()` as well.

PHP:

```
function toEnglishNum($number)
{
    $number = str_replace("۱","1",$number);
    $number = str_replace("۲","2",$number);
    $number = str_replace("۳","3",$number);
    $number = str_replace("۴","4",$number);
    $number = str_replace("۵","5",$number);
    $number = str_replace("۶","6",$number);
    $number = str_replace("۷","7",$number);
    $number = str_replace("۸","8",$number);
    $number = str_replace("۹","9",$number);
    $number = str_replace("۰","0",$number);
    return $number;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function toEnglishNum( num, dontTrim ) {
    var i = 0,
        j = 0,
        dontTrim = dontTrim || false,
        num = dontTrim ? num.toString() : num.toString().trim(),
        len = num.length,
        res = '',
        pos,
        persianNumbers = typeof persianNumber == 'undefined' ?
            [ '۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹' ] :
            persianNumbers;

    for ( ; i < len; i++ )
        if ( ~( pos = persianNumbers.indexOf( num.charAt( i ) ) ) )
            res += pos;
        else
            res += num.charAt( i );
    return res;
};
```

Good Luck

Comment: Deserved 1 point for JavaScript, That is proper to add toEnglishNumber function too.

Comment: @QMaster Thank you for your suggestion. `toEnglshNumber()` added.

Comment: Your welcome @hamed, Thank you for improving answer and I wonder if you look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45541282/1830909 answer and write your thought, Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

the answer is too simple

```js
const a = 1234567890
console.log(new Number(a).toLocaleString('fa-ir')) //۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰
```

Comment: your answer  should have been the top one!

Answer (score 2):

put any persian number in faToEnDigits and it return english digits to you.

```
faToEnDigits(۱۲۳۴) => 1234

enToFaDigits(1234) => ۱۲۳۴
```

```js
var faToEnDigits = function (input) {
        if (input == undefined)
            return;
        var returnModel = "", symbolMap = {
            '۱': '1',
            '۲': '2',
            '۳': '3',
            '۴': '4',
            '۵': '5',
            '۶': '6',
            '۷': '7',
            '۸': '8',
            '۹': '9',
            '۰': '0'
        };
        input = input.toString();
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
            if (symbolMap[input[i]])
                returnModel += symbolMap[input[i]];
            else
                returnModel += input[i];
        return returnModel;
}

var enToFaDigits = function (input) {
        if (input == undefined)
            return;
        var returnModel = "", symbolMap = {
            '1': '۱',
            '2': '۲',
            '3': '۳',
            '4': '۴',
            '5': '۵',
            '6': '۶',
            '7': '۷',
            '8': '۸',
            '9': '۹',
            '0': '۰'
        };
        input = input.toString();
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
            if (symbolMap[input[i]])
                returnModel += symbolMap[input[i]];
            else
                returnModel += input[i];
        return returnModel;
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [Persian-tools](https://github.com/persian-tools/persian-tools) an awesome javascript library for this matter and also many other useful functionalities.

```
import { digitsArToFa, digitsArToEn, digitsEnToFa, digitsFaToEn } from "persian-tools2";

digitsArToFa("٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"); // "۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹"
digitsArToFa("۸۹123۴۵"); // "۸۹123۴۵"
digitsArToFa(456128); // "456128"
digitsArToFa("Text ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"); // "Text ۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹"

digitsArToEn("٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"); // "0123456789"
digitsArToEn("٨٩123٤٥"); // "8912345"
digitsArToEn(456128); // "456128"

digitsArToEn("Text ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"); // "Text 0123456789"

digitsEnToFa("123۴۵۶"); // "۱۲۳۴۵۶"
digitsEnToFa("٤٥٦"); // "٤٥٦"
digitsEnToFa("123۴۵۶"); // "۱۲۳۴۵۶"

digitsFaToEn("123۴۵۶"); // "123456"
digitsFaToEn("۸۹123۴۵"); // "8912345"
digitsFaToEn("۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹"); // "0123456789"
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this code can help you.

```
'12345'.replace(/[0-9]/g, c => String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1728))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your **replaceDigits** function on window.onload which runs when your page is loaded. that's why you notice the delay while converting.

there are some ways to handle it with Javascript, but I guess the best way would be converting the numbers in PHP side.

Answer (score 0):

PHP =>

the best way is :

```
strtr(number_format($price), array('0' => '۰', '1' => '۱', '2' => '۲', '3' => '۳', '4' => '۴', '5' => '۵', '6' => '۶', '7' => '۷', '8' => '۸', '9' => '۹'));
```

Answer (score 0):

heads up :

```
s.replace(/\d/g, d => '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'[d])
```

and function :

```
let convert_english_numbers_to_persisn=(s)=>s.replace(/\d/g, d => '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'[d])
```

Answer (score -1):

Below method replaces all Arabic numbers with English numbers and then replaces all English numbers to Persian numbers:

```
function (value) {
    for (var index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        value = value.replace(String.fromCharCode(index + 1632), index.toString()[0]);
    for (var index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        value = value.replace(index.toString()[0], String.fromCharCode(index + 1776));

    return value;
}
```

Comment: this is not working, for example in "11" it would generate "۱1"

Answer (score -1):

$(document).ready(function () {

```
ConvertNumberToPersion();
```

});

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    ConvertNumberToPersion();
});

function ConvertNumberToPersion() {
    persian = { 0: '۰', 1: '۱', 2: '۲', 3: '۳', 4: '۴', 5: '۵', 6: '۶', 7: '۷', 8: '۸', 9: '۹' };
    function traverse(el) {
        if (el.nodeType == 3) {
            var list = el.data.match(/[0-9]/g);
            if (list != null && list.length != 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                    el.data = el.data.replace(list[i], persian[list[i]]);
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
            traverse(el.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }
    traverse(document.body);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>999</li>
</ul>
```

function ConvertNumberToPersion() {
persian = { 0: '۰', 1: '۱', 2: '۲', 3: '۳', 4: '۴', 5: '۵', 6: '۶', 7: '۷', 8: '۸', 9: '۹' };
function traverse(el) {
if (el.nodeType == 3) {
var list = el.data.match(/[0-9]/g);
if (list != null && list.length != 0) {
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
el.data = el.data.replace(list[i], persian[list[i]]);
}
}
for (var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
traverse(el.childNodes[i]);
}
}
traverse(document.body);
}