# The idiomatic method of collating a non-finite list of "formatting traits" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a self-/internet-taught Javascript amateur and I'm looking to improve the way I code. My current project has some variable "formatting settings" that are altered throughout the course of runtime, depending on starting conditions and some random generation. I currently push these settings to an array and use Array.include() to search for them when required.

Is there a simpler, more efficient, more "traditional" method of doing this? Initially I used a large quantity of boolean variables but this seemed obtuse and made it very difficult to read. Please let me know if there is any way I can improve this question as well.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish, can you post your current code that you feel seems too complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set them as properties on an object instead.

E.g.

```
 settings.newlines = true
 settings.includeFoo = false
 settings.useBar = true
```

To check the value you can then read the property

```
 if(settings.includeFoo) {...}
```

Or if the name of the setting is in a variable, you can use this notation:

```
 var name = 'includeFoo'
 settings[name] = true
 if(settings[name]) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is using objects this way how it is *usually* done?

Comment: Using a settings or options object to pass parameters around is quite common. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089561/in-javascript-what-is-an-options-object